# Loading CSV in Neo4j is time consuming

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher, load

I want load a CDR csv file with 648000 records to neo4j (4.4.10), But it is about 4 days and And it is not yet completed.

My CSV have 648000 records with 7 columns. and the size of file is about 48 MB.
My computer have 100 GB RAM and intel Zeon E5 CPU.

the columns of CSV are:

| OP_Name | TP_Name | Called_Number | OP_ANI | Setup_Time | Duration | OP_Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

the code that I use to load CSV in Neo4j is:

````
```Cypher
:auto load csv with headers from 'file:///cdr.csv' as line FIELDTERMINATOR  ','
    with line
    where line['Called_Number'] is not null and line['OP_ANI'] is not null
    with line['OP_ANI'] as OP_Phone,
        (CASE line['OP_Name']
            WHEN 'TIC' THEN 'IRAN'
            ELSE 'Foreign' END) AS OP_country,
        line['Called_Number'] as Called_Phone,
        (CASE line['TP_Name']
            WHEN 'TIC' THEN 'IRAN'
            ELSE 'Foreign' END) AS TP_country,
        line['Setup_Time'] as Setup_Time, 
        line['Duration'] as Duration, 
        line['OP_Price'] as OP_Price
    
    call {
        with  OP_Phone, OP_country, Called_Phone, TP_country, Setup_Time, Duration, OP_Price
        
MERGE (c:Customer{phone: toInteger(Called_Phone)})
            on create set c.country = TP_country
            WITH c, OP_Phone, OP_country, Called_Phone, TP_country, Setup_Time, Duration, OP_Price
            CALL apoc.create.addLabels( c, [ c.country ] ) YIELD node
        
MERGE (c2:Customer{phone: toInteger(OP_Phone)})
            on create set c2.country = OP_country
            WITH c2, OP_Phone, OP_country, Called_Phone, TP_country, Setup_Time, Duration, OP_Price, c
            CALL apoc.create.addLabels( c2, [ c2.country ] )  YIELD node
        
        MERGE (c2)-[r:CALLED{setupTime: Setup_Time, 
                    duration: Duration,
                    OP_Price: OP_Price}]->(c)
       
    } IN TRANSACTIONS

```
````

How can I speed up the load operation?

Comment: Try creating an index on `phone` property of `Customer`. Like this: `CREATE INDEX phone IF NOT EXISTS
FOR (n:Customer)
ON (n.phone)`

Comment: Great. I will post that as an answer so that other users can also take advantage of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MERGE` acts as an upsert in Neo4j. So the statement:

```
MERGE (c:Customer{phone: toInteger(Called_Phone)})
```

checks if there is a `Customer` node with the given phone number is there or not. If it is, it performs the update otherwise creates the node. When there is a large number of nodes, this lookup can be very slow, and CSV import will be slow overall. Creating an index on the `phone` property of `Customer` should do the trick. You can create the index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX phone IF NOT EXISTS FOR (n:Customer) ON (n.phone)
```